# Change "No Access" status to Member

Tags: ios

Accidentally gave a developer 'No Access' permission.

Now, he is not in the People list for me to edit.

How can I get back to his account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Well, this is about the Apple Developer Program, of which there are many unclosed questions around here.